# Why don't calcium chloride and sodium nitrate react?

Tags: solubility, reactivity

$$\ce{CaCl2 + 2NaNO3 -> 2NaCl + Ca(NO3)2}$$

Why doesn't the above reaction occur? Does it have to do with the metal activity series or solubility rules?

Answer (score 6):

It's because all the species are soluble in water and there is no driving force such as precipitation or gas evolution. You just have a mixture of ions.